# In nginx how to get reponse from localhost which has been sent from localhost?

Tags: php, nginx, curl

I am trying to send a curl request from one localhost php page (a.php) to the same localhost another php page (b.php). I am completely new to this nginx thing, really need help on this.

```
-----------
nginx.conf
-----------

worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

```
---------
start.bat
---------
@ECHO OFF
start C:\nginx-1.18.0\nginx.exe
start C:\php7.0.29\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\php7.0.29\php.ini
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1>NUL
echo Starting nginx
echo .
echo .
echo .
ping 127.0.0.1 >NUL
EXIT
```

```
------
a.php
------
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/b.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

```
------
b.php
------
<?php 
echo "Test";
exit();
?>
```

```
---------
error.log
---------
[error] 6596#9904: *2 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /a.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
[error] 6596#9904: *13 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /b.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

I have used the above nginx configuration, to send request from a.php page to b.php page. After running a.php on the browser it keeps on loading and finally after a long time, it responds with "An error occurred" and on inspect the error shows "504 error".

Comment: Unless you are trying to do something that I can't comprehend, this really feels like you are doing something overly complex. Do you want to experiment with Nginx, PHP, curl or something else? Right now you are mixing a lot of related but independent things together and they could be getting in the way. If is is Nginx, I would really recommend getting a VM that runs *nix and just install it through a package manager. If is is PHP, I'd just run that through PHP's native CLI or daemon (`-b`).

Comment: @ChrisHaas This is exact problem i am facing
https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows/issues/58#issuecomment-362473764

Comment: The reason that I asked about the overall setup was that starting Nginx from a batch file (which isn't wrong) just felt like  it could lead people _here_ to try to fix that instead of your actual problem. Nginx either runs or doesn't, and it is either configured correctly or it isn't, and your OS/application can either connect to it or it can't. With the context of the link you posted, is seems like it is the latter problem. I unfortunately don't have an answer, however, because I dev locally through Symfony's CLI binary.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch file to start everything won't work like this...

nginx starts, but never returns control back to the script. The php-fpm wasn't started.

To start nginx as service, use `start nginx` from within the installation folder.

Note that the php-fpm will also not return after start. Open a new CLI and ping localhost or run a.php through a browser, which should be working by then..

hth

Comment: Everything is working fine php, nginx and mysql, only problem is working with curl request from localhost to localhost

This post shows the same error which i am facing:
https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows/issues/58#issuecomment-362473764